# How To fetch a specific value from all children in firebase database and then add it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have `Price` stored in `orders` as shown in the image. And all i want to do is take the price from each child. Even though the method is called as many times as the number of children in `orders`, the `for` loop didnt work. The `total` is coming out wrong.

What `Toast` displayed was addition of 53 and 25 then 25 and 15 and then 15 and 80. It should be displaying total of 25,15,80,53 instead.

[UI of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llook.png)

[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHGgQ.png)

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ShowDataItems, 
  CheckoutActivity.ShowDataViewHolder>(ShowDataItems.class, 
  R.layout.show_data_items_checkout, ShowDataViewHolder.class, myRef) {

        public void populateViewHolder(final ShowDataViewHolder viewHolder, 
    final ShowDataItems model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.ItemName(model.getItemName());
            viewHolder.Price(model.getPrice());
            viewHolder.Image_Count(model.getItemCount());



            viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
             {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


   myRef.child(viewHolder.ItemName(model.getItemName())).child("ItemName")
   .setValue(null);

   myRef.child(viewHolder.ItemName(model.getItemName())).child("ItemCount")
   .setValue(null);
                    myRef.child(viewHolder.ItemName(model.getItemName())).child("Price").setValue(null);

                }
            });

            //OnClick Item
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new 
    View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    int s = position;
                    mFirebaseAdapter.getRef((s));

                }
            });

            calling++;

            for(int i = 0; i<calling; i++)
            {

                total = temp +price;
                temp = price;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ total, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some logic error, here's how you should do the count. I have added the "toast shown checker" to make sure that only one toast is shown each time.

```
... class' variable

private Toast toast;
private int total = 0;

... inside the populateViewHolder method

total = total + price;
if (toast != null) {
    toast.cancel();
}
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Hope this helps :)